# Uint16Array access byteOffset 1, 3, 5 etc

Tags: javascript, firefox, opera, typed-arrays

```
new Uint16Array(ArrayBuffer, byteOffset, length);
```

For `Uint16` (word) `byteOffset` can only be 0, 2, 4, 6 etc. How access to 2nd, 4th byte? (`byteOffset` = 1, 3 etc)
`DataView` is solution for Chrome but not for FireFox (dont know about opera at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the buffer into a `Uint8Array` (for separate bytes), and then read from that array:

```
var a = new Uint16Array(10);

// fill `a` with data
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) a[i] = i * 10;

var b = new Uint8Array(a.buffer); // `b` contains bytes of `a`, e.g. use `b[1]`
```

---

```
var orig = new Uint8Array(buffer);

var sub = new Uint16Array(orig.subarray(1, 2)); // from index 1 to 2, so second byte

var word = sub[0]; // 2nd byte as Uint16
```

---

About your posted case:

```
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(65535);
var u8s = new Uint8Array(buf);
u8s[0] = 0x01;
u8s[1] = 0x02;
u8s[2] = 0x03;
var x = new Uint8Array(u8s.subarray(1, 3)).buffer; // buffer from subarray
                                                   // 1 to 3 because 1 word is 2 bytes
sub = new Uint16Array(x); // create Uint16Array from it
sub[0]; // 770, which is:   (3 << 8) | 2   (it is big-endian)
```

Comment: @Demion: You can read the bytes of `a`'s buffer with `b[n]`, with `n` some index.

Comment: For example I have ArrayBuffer and I need read from 2nd byte to word (uint16) or to short (int16)

Comment: @Demion: I think it returns `770`, because the part on the right counts for more, i.e. `0x302`. Please see my edit again.

Comment: var sendbuf = new ArrayBuffer(65535);
 var buf = new Int8Array(sendbuf, 0, 2);
 var short = new Int16Array(1);
 short[0] = -1;
 var sb = new Int8Array(short);
 for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
 {
  buf[i] = sb[i];
  alert(buf[i]);
 }                                                             Should this code return OxFF and 0xFF (-1). It returns 0xFF 0x00

Comment: @Demion: Yes, you should pass the buffer, i.e. `new Int8Array(short.buffer)`. The buffer contains the underlying bytes, which you need a view for. You're currently just converting the `-1` word into an `Int8`.